# django-guardian get_obj_perms can't find my object?

Tags: python, django

I'm testing django-guardian with a simple leaderboard app. The permissions themselves work properly but I'm trying to access them inside a template using `get_obj_perms`. I'm using a generic `ListView` along with the `objects_list`. When I tried this code:

```
{% for board in object_list %}
   {% get_obj_perms request.user for board as "board_perms" %}
```

I get an error:

> Variable does not exist

I know that board is accessing each item in object list because if I remove the `get_obj_perms` line everything works fine. So it seems I'm in correct in thinking board is my object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I was missing the request processor in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
'django.core.context_processors.request'
```

Answer (score 0):

if your want to use tag *`get_obj_perms`*  in template , you must be add it at the top of template file:

```
{% load guardian_tags %}
```